# Template specializations - giving an optional template

Tags: c++, templates

I'm struggeling a bit with template specializations.

Let's say I'm implementing a class that can convert between different objects. Here I'll just cast between basic types for simplicity.

```
class Converter
{
    public:
       Converter() {};

    template <typename ConvT,
              typename FromT>
    static
    ConvT
    convert(From type);
};


template <typename ConvT,
          typename FromT>
ConvT
Converter::convert(FromT type)
{
   return static_cast<ConvT>(type);
}

template <>
double
Converter::convert<double,int>(int type)
{
  return 22.2;
}
```

Now I can do things like this

```
float myFloat = Converter::convert<float>(5);
double myTwentyTwoPointTwo = Converter::convert<double>(42);
```

I would like to be able to also specify an optional template parameter that will become a container for the type.

```
// Retrns a std::vector<dobule> with one element, 22.2.
std::vector<double> myDoubleVec = Converter::convert<double, std::vector>(42);
```

Is there a way to expand this class so that it will have this feature?

Edit: This would be fine:

```
Converter::convert<double, int, std::vector>(42);
```

Comment: like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96053088dffffacd) or [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef93eac04d666798) ?

Comment: I can't seem to upvote your answere?

Comment: What excatly does this do? template <typename T> using identity = T;

Comment: identity serves here as a no-op if you don't provide any template template argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Option #1

A single primary template to handle both conversions - to a scalar or a container:

```
template <typename T>
using identity = T;

struct Converter
{
    template <typename ConvT,
              template <typename...> class ConT = identity,
              typename FromT>
    static ConT<ConvT> convert(FromT type);
};

template <typename ConvT,
          template <typename...> class ConT,
          typename FromT>
ConT<ConvT> Converter::convert(FromT type)
{
    return ConT<ConvT>{ static_cast<ConvT>(type) };
}
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a031754abe9cd0e)

#### Option #2

A separate overload for containers:

```
struct Converter
{
    //...

    template <typename ConvT,
              template <typename...> class ConT,
              typename FromT>
    static ConT<ConvT> convert(FromT type);
};

template <typename ConvT,
          template <typename...> class ConT,
          typename FromT>
ConT<ConvT> Converter::convert(FromT type)
{
    return ConT<ConvT>{ static_cast<ConvT>(type) };
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b96b3265d035706)

#### Option #3

C++03 version, a separate overload for `std::vector`, `std::list` and `std::deque` containers:

```
struct Converter
{
    //...

    template <typename ConvT,
              template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> > class ConT,
              typename FromT>
    static ConT<ConvT> convert(FromT type);
};

template <typename ConvT,
          template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> > class ConT,
          typename FromT>
ConT<ConvT> Converter::convert(FromT type)
{
    return ConT<ConvT>(1, static_cast<ConvT>(type));
}
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59b42f0733d3a684)

*Tests:*

```
std::vector<double> v = Converter::convert<double, std::vector>(42);
double d = Converter::convert<double>(42);
```

Comment: Do I need c++11 to compile this?

Comment: Both require C++11 -> you need a default function template parameter, and you need a parameter pack unless you want more overloads

Comment: I forgot to say that I cannot use C++11. Although this solution was elegant, I might have to try something else. Could option number two maybe be changed so that it compiles without C++11?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to just pass the container type directly:

```
#include <vector>

template<typename C, typename T>
C ConvertAndPutIntoContainer(T t) 
{
    C c;
    c.push_back(static_cast<typename C::value_type>(t));
    return c;    
}

// usage
auto x = ConvertAndPutIntoContainer<std::vector<double>>(23);
```